# Fetch Search results using facebook-sdk in python

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-access-token

**When I type something in facebook search, i get results as per the search term. What kind of permission do i require to access the search results.**

I have gone through the link [Facebook Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31147371/using-python-for-facebook-to-search), but then i didn't get the any data using the search term through facebook-sdk implemented in python. I got results when I manually typed the search term in facebook search box.

Below is my code

```
import requests
import facebook
import json


def pp(o):
  print(json.dumps(o,indent=1))

ACCESS_TOKEN = 'EAAGCJ6G1tMIBAPfcGvUXMe0v5aRPOTBPGr5gepZBZB1gvfpyBeeuLJyphy1QXbuP25pzROlPo4ixqtap9cZCixW3ZC2pwBpUVOcm4GZCADE0GBxFryIniiYxGHS2MZCUAp3apRBic1mUhhOD3e9DBUrqbAbVGzAOcafb2BjhsXd5YWdTyNCf46LlZB8sHtj76RZCjjBHhN0NoDXVjDslttDOUWktlIoSsBoi38QYljSSLgZDZD'

base_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me'
g = facebook.GraphAPI(ACCESS_TOKEN,version="2.11")
pp(g.request("search", {"q" : "social web", "type" : "page"}))
```

When i ran the above code, the results are

```
{
 "data": []
}
```

But then when i typed the same search term in facebook search, the results i got was

[image]

Is there anything i am missing. **The access token was user access token, do i need any other token to access the search results.**  If so, can you help me, please

Comment: The search on facebook.com and what is available in the API are two completely different things.

Comment: I didn't get you @WizKid

Comment: Just because you can do something on facebook.com doesn't mean you can do it in the API.

Comment: So you are telling me i cannot scrape search results from facebook

Comment: Correct you can not scrap facebook.com

Comment: Ok. I didn't know that.

Comment: Is it possible to scrape posts from a page. I have seen various github snippets which does that, however nothing works.@WizKid

Comment: Facebook doesn't allow you to scrape.